# Meteor secure subscribe & publish

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code needs to publish one document which has field `plateNum` match value that is entered by the user.
 Why is it not returning any thing? How to fix it?

//server.publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('myCol', function (plate) {
  if (this.userId && plate) {
    return myCol.find({plateNum: plate}, {fields: {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, engineSize: 1 }});
  }
});
```

The values of the fields 'a', 'b', 'c' may not be ready at the time of the user request but will be calculated by a backend worker and update the `myCol`

//client.main.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('myCol', dict.get('plateNum'));  //<== stored info from user

Template.footer.events({
  'click #info': () => {
    searching = '<span class="note">Searching...</span>';
    let plate = document.getElementById('plateNum').value;
    plate = plate.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase().trim();  //
    dict.set('plateNum', plate);  //<=== store user info here

    let doc = myCol.findOne({plateNum: plate});
    if (!doc || !doc.a) Meteor.call('aaa', plate);
    if (doc && !doc.b) Meteor.call('bbb', {plateNum: plate}, () => {});
    if (doc && doc.c && !doc.c) Meteor.call('ccc', {plateNum: plate}, () => {});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because at the time your client code subscribes to `myCol` the `this.userId` is null therefore nothing is returned by server.

To fix this you need to make sure the user has been authenticated prior to `subscribe`

**Update**

This is the code you could use to fix it:

```
Template.footer.onCreated(function() {
  // use this.autorun over Tracker.autorun
  // so that the code below will be clear on onDestroy event
  this.autorun(function() {
    if(Meteor.userId()) {
      Meteor.subscribe('myCol', dict.get('plateNum'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hey I just updated the answer, if there are any unclear things just comment and I will explain